# WPF/XAML Button.Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a bit puzzled. It's not a big problem, but does anyone have a explanation to why this

```
<Button Command="{Binding CancelButtonClickCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Height="16" Width="16">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid Background="{Binding CancelImage}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

works, when this

```
<Button Command="{Binding CheckButtonClickCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="16" Width="16">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding CheckImage}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

dosen't? 
The difference being that I use a `<Grid Background="{Binding CancelImage}"/>` in the first, and a `<Image Source="{Binding CheckImage}"/>` in the one that dosen't work. 
In the latter the image isn't visible, and I don't even Command isn't even called.

Thanks a lot in advance
/C

Comment: Is CheckImage a valid ImageSource?

Comment: @Lennart Both CheckImage and CancelImage are ImageBrush types

Comment: Well, that's the issue. Grid.Background expects a Brush as a type (which works in your case), while Image.Source expects an ImageSource (which doesn't work, since you can't it implicitly convert from ImageBrush).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid.Background binds to a `Brush` type, while Image.Source requires an `ImageSource`. The easiest way to solve that would be to expose the Brush's `ImageSource` property in your CheckImage binding. If that's not possible you could also attach a converter to the Image.Source binding and return an ImageSource from the brush you're binding to.